# cant set style attribute value javascript / typescript

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, object, jsx

I am trying to set the style for an element from a supplied object. like so:

```
function DOMparseChildren(children: any) {
    return children.map((child: any) => {
        if(typeof child === 'string') {
            return document.createTextNode(child);
        }
        return child;
    })
}

function nonNull(val: any, fallback: any) { return Boolean(val) ? val : fallback };

function DOMparseNode(element: any, properties: any, children: any) {
    const el = document.createElement(element) as HTMLElement;
    // here it is possible to set style...
    // el["style"]["color"] = "red";
    Object.keys(nonNull(properties, {})).forEach(key => {
        if(key === 'style') {
            Object.keys(nonNull(properties[key], {})).forEach(styleKey => {
                console.log(element + "." + key + "." + styleKey + " = " + properties[key][styleKey]);
                // here it is not possible.......
                el[key][styleKey] = properties[key][styleKey];
                el["style"]["color"] = "red";
            });
        }
        el[key] = properties[key];
    })
    DOMparseChildren(children).forEach((child: any) => {
        el.appendChild(child);
    });
    return el;
}

function DOMcreateElement(element: any, properties: any, ...children: any) {
    if(typeof element === 'function') {
        return element( { ...nonNull( properties, {} ), children } );
    }
    return DOMparseNode(element, properties, children);
}
```

usage, it is supposed to help with the following scenario:

```
document.body.appendChild(<div style={{color: 'red'}}></div>)
```

the `console.log` does log the correct output: **h1.style.color = red**

So why doesn't it apply my style right below the `console.log` ??

I don't get any errors.. Which makes debugging so much harder :(

If more context is needed please let me know!

with the ultimate goal being to replace the
`el["style"]["color"] = "red";`
with
`el[key][styleKey] = properties[key][styleKey];`

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't apply your style? Did you append the element to the body?

Comment: You're applying the same style that you applied at the top of the function. How can you tell that it's not working?

Comment: @hev1 yes it does apply my element, there is more code to it but i left that out.

Comment: @Barmar I tried each line separate of course :)

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar I have posted all relevant code, you need jsx to make it work it is supposted to be used as the jsxFactory in a typescript (.tsx) project. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
el[key] = properties[key];
```

is overwriting all the styles that were set in the `properties[key]` loop. You should put that in an `else` block so it's only done for `non-style` properties.

```
function DOMparseNode(element: any, properties: any, children: any) {
    const el = document.createElement(element) as HTMLElement;
    // here it is possible to set style...
    // el["style"]["color"] = "red";
    Object.keys(nonNull(properties, {})).forEach(key => {
        if(key === 'style') {
            Object.keys(nonNull(properties[key], {})).forEach(styleKey => {
                console.log(element + "." + key + "." + styleKey + " = " + properties[key][styleKey]);
                // here it is not possible.......
                el[key][styleKey] = properties[key][styleKey];
                el["style"]["color"] = "red";
            });
        } else {
            el[key] = properties[key];
        }
    })
    DOMparseChildren(children).forEach((child: any) => {
        el.appendChild(child);
    });
    return el;
}
```

Comment: yeah, how did I miss that.. But thanks that solved 1 hour of pure head scratching :)